# how to show that $\frac{d}{dr}J_0(\lambda r)= -\lambda J_1(\lambda r)$? as a bessel series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

we already know that  the Bessel series expansions is
$$ 
J_n(\lambda r)=({\lambda r \over 2})^n \sum_m^{\infty}({\lambda r \over 2})^{2m}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(n+m)!}$$
we want to prove that
$$\frac{d}{dr}J_0(\lambda r)= -\lambda J_1(\lambda r)$$
we first notice that
$$ \frac{d}{dr}J_0(\lambda r)= \lambda J_0^{'}(\lambda r)$$
so the Eq.(2)becomes
$$\lambda J_0^{'}(\lambda r)=-\lambda J_1(\lambda r)$$
In other words  we just need to prove that
$$J_0^{'}(\lambda r)+J_1(\lambda r)=0$$
obviously
$$J_0(\lambda r)=\sum_m^{\infty}({\lambda r \over 2})^{2m}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!m!} $$
so
$$J_0^{'}(\lambda r)=2m\sum_m^{\infty}({\lambda r \over 2})^{2m-1}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!m!}$$
moreover
$$J_1(\lambda r)=({\lambda r \over 2})^1\sum_m^{\infty}({\lambda r \over 2})^{2m}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(1+m)!}$$
so that
$$J_0^{'}(\lambda r)+J_1(\lambda r)=2m\sum_m^{\infty}({\lambda r \over 2})^{2m-1}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!m!}+({\lambda r \over 2})^1\sum_m^{\infty}({\lambda r \over 2})^{2m}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(1+m)!}$$
after some simplification I notice I  just need to prove that
$$ (\frac{\lambda r}{2})^2 \frac{1}{m+1}+2m =0 $$
and I am stuck at here.
I am just wondering, where am I wrong?

Comment: You can drop the $\lambda$, as $J_0'(r) = -J_1(r)$ implies $dJ_0(\lambda r)/dr = -\lambda J_1(\lambda r)$ by the chain rule.

Comment: why$J_0^{'}( r)=-J_1(r)$?

Comment: When you differentiated $J_0$ you pulled the $m$ outside the sum. Also a keep track of your factors of $2$.

Comment: $\sum_m^\infty$ is missing the start value for $m$. That could give you a hint on how to make $J_0' + J_1$ work out the way you want.

Comment: @ eyeballfrog both series are from  m=0 to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off, some errors. The start of the sum is $m= 0$. The derivative of $(\lambda r/2)^{2m}$ with respect to $\lambda r$ is $m(\lambda r/2)^{2m-1}$, not $2m(\lambda r/2)^{2m-1}$. Also you can't take $m$ out of the sum like that, since that's what's being summed over. Cleaning all that up and letting $u = \lambda r$ for brevity gives
$$J_0^{'}(u)+J_1(u)=\sum_{m= 0}^{\infty}m\left({ u \over 2}\right)^{2m-1}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!m!}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left({u \over 2}\right)^{2m+1}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(1+m)!}
$$
To solve the problem, note that the first term in the $J_0'$ sum is $0$. Thus, you can have the sum start at $m=1$ instead. What do you notice about the $m=1$ term of the $J_0'$ sum and the $m=0$ term of the $J_1$ sum? What about the next terms? Can you make an argument that they all sum to $0$?

Answer (score 0):

ok I finally got it.
thank you very much @eyeballfrog.
since the first sum
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}$$
I could just replace the second sum (m) as (m-1) started from 1
so the second sum becomes
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}   \left({ u \over 2}\right)^{2m-1} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!m!}$$
so we add both up we  get
$$\sum_{m= 1}^{\infty}m\left({ u \over 2}\right)^{2m-1}   \frac{(-1)^m}{m!m!}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}   \left({ u \over 2}\right)^{2m-1} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!m!}$$
Then apparently
$$m((-1)^m+(-1)^{m-1})) ==0$$ constantly.
thus the entire equation becomes 0 all the time.
Again, Thank you very much @eyeballfrog!!!